Truncate partition and merge it SQL server
This post continuity of Table Partition design Suggestion.
I have tried to truncate older partition and merging it. But I am getting an error "Invalid partition number 8 specified for table 'dbo.STYTOTAL_RAW', partition number can range from 1 to 6."  Looks like once it merge the while loop is getting invalid for the max partition number.
For testing I used 3 days but the original requirement is delete partition older than 90 days.
As per @DanGuzman adding PF as well. The complete script is available. in my first post. I have linked that top of this post as well.
--Create function, copy from your script
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION PF_myDateRange ( [datetime2](7))
AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES 
(
'2024-06-01 23:59:59.9999999',
'2024-07-01 23:59:59.9999999',
'2024-08-01 23:59:59.9999999',
'2024-09-01 23:59:59.9999999',
'2024-10-01 23:59:59.9999999',
'2024-10-21 23:59:59.9999999' -- take the max day and round with 12 AM ex: 2024-10-21 00:00:00.0000000
)
GO
use DB_Partition

--Invalid partition number 8 specified for table 'dbo.STYTOTAL_RAW', partition number can range from 1 to 6.

-- We can loop through the partition number directly from the table
--TRUNCATE TABLE [STYTOTAL_RAW] WITH (PARTITIONS (4));

declare @cmd_1 nvarchar(max)
declare @cmd_2 nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @partition_no bigint
DECLARE @PartitionFunction_name nvarchar(128)
DECLARE @PartitionFunction_Upper_value datetime2(7)
DECLARE @minrow int
DECLARE @maxrow int


select  @minrow = MIN(p.partition_number), @maxrow  = MAX(p.partition_number)
    from sys.indexes i  
    join sys.partitions p ON i.object_id=p.object_id AND i.index_id=p.index_id  
    join sys.partition_schemes ps on ps.data_space_id = i.data_space_id  
    join sys.partition_functions pf on pf.function_id = ps.function_id  
    left join sys.partition_range_values rv on rv.function_id = pf.function_id AND rv.boundary_id = p.partition_number
    join sys.allocation_units au  ON au.container_id = p.hobt_id   
    join sys.filegroups fg  ON fg.data_space_id = au.data_space_id  
    where i.object_id = object_id('STYTOTAL_RAW') 
    and rv.value < DATEADD(DAY, -3, SYSDATETIME()) 
    

select @minrow,@maxrow


while (@minrow <=@maxrow)
 begin

select  @partition_no=partition_number,@PartitionFunction_name=pf.name,@PartitionFunction_Upper_value=cast(rv.value as datetime2(7))
    from sys.indexes i  
    join sys.partitions p ON i.object_id=p.object_id AND i.index_id=p.index_id  
    join sys.partition_schemes ps on ps.data_space_id = i.data_space_id  
    join sys.partition_functions pf on pf.function_id = ps.function_id  
    left join sys.partition_range_values rv on rv.function_id = pf.function_id AND rv.boundary_id = p.partition_number
    join sys.allocation_units au  ON au.container_id = p.hobt_id   
    join sys.filegroups fg  ON fg.data_space_id = au.data_space_id  
    where i.object_id = object_id('STYTOTAL_RAW') 
    and rv.value < DATEADD(DAY, -3, SYSDATETIME()) 
    and p.partition_number = @minrow



SET @cmd_1 = N'TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.STYTOTAL_RAW WITH (PARTITIONS (' + convert(NVARCHAR(128),@partition_no) + N'));'
print @cmd_1
--EXEC sys.sp_executesql @cmd_1
SET @cmd_2 = N'ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION ['+ @PartitionFunction_name+ '] () merge range ('''+convert (NVARCHAR(128), @PartitionFunction_Upper_value) +''');'


print @cmd_2
--EXEC sys.sp_executesql @cmd_2

set @minrow =@minrow +1 
end

Any suggestion please.
Thanks for your help.

If you are merging right from the lower partition numbers then those partitions will disappear as you loop around.
Probably makes the most sense to just recalculate the partition number each time, and break when you get no result.
declare @cmd nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @partition_no bigint;
DECLARE @PartitionFunction_name nvarchar(128);
DECLARE @PartitionFunction_Upper_value datetime2(7);

while 1=1
begin

    select top (1)
      @partition_no = p.partition_number,
      @PartitionFunction_name = pf.name,
      @PartitionFunction_Upper_value = try_cast(rv.value as datetime2(7))
    from sys.indexes i  
    join sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.object_id AND i.index_id = p.index_id  
    join sys.partition_schemes ps on ps.data_space_id = i.data_space_id  
    join sys.partition_functions pf on pf.function_id = ps.function_id  
    join sys.partition_range_values rv on rv.function_id = pf.function_id AND rv.boundary_id = p.partition_number
    where i.object_id = object_id('STYTOTAL_RAW') 
      and try_cast(rv.value as datetime2(7)) < DATEADD(DAY, -3, SYSDATETIME()) 
    order by partition_number desc;

    if @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        break;


    SET @cmd = N'TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.STYTOTAL_RAW WITH (PARTITIONS (' + convert(NVARCHAR(128), @partition_no) + N'));';
    print @cmd;
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @cmd;

    SET @cmd = N'ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION '+ QUOTENAME(@PartitionFunction_name) + ' () merge range (''' + convert (NVARCHAR(128), @PartitionFunction_Upper_value) + ''');';
    print @cmd;
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @cmd;

end;

db<>fiddle
